# C# - break out large string into multiple smaller strings for export to a database

Tags: c#

C# newb here - I have a script written in C# which takes the contents of several fields of the internal database of an application (Contoso Application, in this case) and exports them to a SQL Server Database table.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Contoso.Application.Api;
using Contoso.Application.Commands;
using System.Linq;

public class Script
{
    public static bool ExportData(DataExportArguments args)
    {
        try
        {
            var sqlStringTest = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            sqlStringTest.DataSource = "SQLserverName";
            sqlStringTest.InitialCatalog = "TableName";
            sqlStringTest.IntegratedSecurity = True;
            sqlStringTest.UserID = "userid";
            sqlStringTest.Password = "password";


            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlStringTest.ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (IExportReader dataReader = args.Data.GetTable())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {   
                        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

                            sqlCommand.CommandText = 
                            @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] (
                            Id, 
                            Url,
                            articleText)
                             VALUES (
                            @Id, 
                            @Url,
                            @articleText)";

                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", dataReader.GetStringValue("Id"));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Url", dataReader.GetStringValue("Url"));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleText", 
                                    dataReader.Columns.Any(x => x.Name == "articleText") 
                                    ? dataReader.GetStringValue("articleText") 
                                    : (object)DBNull.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            args.WriteDebug(exp.ToString(), DebugMessageType.Error);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

FYI - `articleText` is of type `nvarchar(max)`

What I'm trying to accomplish: sometimes the data in the `articleText` field is short, sometimes it is very long.  What I need to do is break out a record into multiple records when the string in a given `articleText` field is greater than 10,000 characters. So if a given `articleText` field is 25,000 characters, there would be 3 records exported: first one would have an `articleText` field of 10,000 characters, 2nd, 10,000 characters, 3rd, 5,000 characters.

Further to this requirement, I need to ensure that if the character cutoff for each record falls in the middle of a word (which will likely happen most of the time) that I account for that.

Therefore, as an example, if we have a record in the application's internal database with `Id` of 1, `Url` of www.contoso.com, and `articleText` of 28,000 characters, I would want to export 3 records to SQL Server as such:

```
Record 1:

Id: 1
Url: www.contoso.com
articleText: if articleText greater than 10,000 characters, export characters 1-10,000, else export entirety of articleText.

Record 2:

Id: 1
Url: www.contoso.com
articleText: assuming Record 2 only exists if Record 1 was greater than 10k character, export characters 9,990-20,000 (start at character 9,990 in case Record 1 cuts off at the middle of a word).

Record 3:

Id: 1
Url: www.contoso.com
articleText: export characters 19,900-28,000 (or alternatively, 19,900 through end of string).
```

For any given export session, there are thousands of records in the internal database to be exported (hence the while loop).  Approximately 20% of the records will meet the criteria of `articleText` exceeding 10k characters, so for any that don't, we absolutely only want to export one record.  Further, although my example above only goes to 28k characters, this script needs to be able to accommodate any size.

I'm a bit stumped at how one would go about accomplishing something like this.  I believe the first step is to get a character count for `articleText` to determine how many records need to be exported.  From there, I feel I've gone down a rabbit hole. Any suggestions on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT #1: to clarify on the cutoff requirement - the reason the above is the approach I'm suggesting to handle the cutoff is because the article may have a person's name in it.  Simply finding a space and cutting it off there wouldn't work because it's possible you would split between a first and last name.  The approach I mention above would meet our requirements because the word or name only needs to exist in its entirety in **one** of the records.

Further, reassembly of the separated records in SQL Server is not a requirement and therefore not necessary.

Comment: Not sure what your word strategy is. It sounds like you export 1-10000 in the first record, then _"9,990-20,000 (start at character 9,990 in case Record 1 cuts off at the middle of a word)."_ as the next - won't those extra 10 characters complicate things when reassembling? How about taking the first 10k characters, then walking back from the end until you find a space, then save that as the first record: then take the next 10k and repeat as necessary?

Comment: The Id stays the same and you have no other means to control the order of these 3 rows? If you query your export you might end up with interchanged rows.

Comment: I think problem isn't in this code, it's in the database, you also have to show your table structure, i think your column have a fix size which is truncating your characters from size about the column size

Comment: You can use a loop, along with [`Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8), to get chunks of characters from a string: `int maxChars = 10000; for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += maxChars) { string truncatedArticle = string.Concat(articleText.Skip(i * maxChars).Take(maxChars)); // Add this truncatedArticle "chunk" to your db here }`. Of course now you'll likely need a joining table to associated multiple chunks of data with a single record.

Comment: Why do you want to split the text on storage? Your field is already `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Why not store the entire text block and split it up on the `SELECT` statement if you really want to?

Comment: @stuartd the space approach won't work because a space could still be between someone's first and last name.  We need the person's entire name in at least one of the records.  I am going to edit my question now to include this.  Good catch.

Comment: _"the space approach won't work because a space could still be between someone's first and last name. We need the person's entire name in at least one of the records"_ - that's going to [get complicated](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) - as other comments are asking, why do you need to split the text up?

Comment: The text needs to be split up because we have a search index which ingests our SQL Table data, and that search index can only accommodate fields of 10,000 characters or less.  The requirements for inserting the data in an already broken up format, as opposed to breaking it up in SQL after insertion, is because we want to separate it on the front-end in order that we don't waste precious resources of our SQL Server, which is unfortunately somewhat under-powered due to unavoidable cost limitations.

Comment: You might need to use 'padding' of more than 10 letters, then, as names can [be longer than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.)

Comment: @stuartd agreed, and that's certainly not an issue to pad it more.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a start: it's not very efficient, admittedly, but just to illustrate how it might be done:

```cs
void Main()
{
    string text = "012345 6789012 3456789012 34567890 1234567" + 
        "0123 456789 01234567 8901234567 8901234567" + 
        "012345 67890123456 78901234567890123456" + 
        "0123456 7890123456 789012345 6789012345" + 
        "012345 678901234 5678901234 5678901234" + 
        "01234567 89012345678 901234567890123" + 
        "ABCDEFGHI JLMNOPQES TUVWXYZ";

    int startingPoint = 0;
    int chunkSize = 50;
    int padding = 10;
    List<string> chunks = new List<string>();
    do
    {
        if (startingPoint == 0)
        {
            chunks.Add(new string(text.Take(chunkSize).ToArray()));
        }
        else 
        {
            chunks.Add(new string(text.Skip(startingPoint).Take(chunkSize).ToArray()));
        }

        startingPoint = startingPoint + chunkSize - padding;
    }
    while (startingPoint < text.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Original length: {0}", text.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Chunk count: {0}", chunks.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Expected new length: {0}", text.Length + (chunks.Count -1) * padding);
    Console.WriteLine("Actual new length: {0}", chunks.Sum(c => c.Length));

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Chunks:");

    foreach (var chunk in chunks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chunk);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Original length: 263
>   Chunk count: 7
>   Expected new length: 323
>   Actual new length: 323

Chunks:

```
012345 6789012 3456789012 34567890 12345670123 456
670123 456789 01234567 8901234567 8901234567012345
4567012345 67890123456 789012345678901234560123456
4560123456 7890123456 789012345 6789012345012345 6
45012345 678901234 5678901234 567890123401234567 8
01234567 89012345678 901234567890123ABCDEFGHI JLMN
EFGHI JLMNOPQES TUVWXYZ
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this stuartd! This looks like a great start.  I am going to pull this into my script, make some updates, and if this works, I'll mark it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to tokenize the input to be able split it sensibly. In order to do that, you *have* to be able to make some assumptions about the input.

For example, you could split the input on the last *end-of-sentence* that occurs prior to the 10K character boundary. But, you have to be able to make concrete assumptions with the input about what constitutes an *end-of-sentence*. If you can assume that the input is well-punctuated and grammatically correct, then a simple regex like `[^.!?]+[.!?] {1,2}[A-Z]` can be used to detect the end of a sentence, where the sentence ends with ".", "!", or "?", is followed by at least one but no more than two spaces, and the next character is a capital letter. Since the
following capital letter is included in the match, you just drop back one character position and split.

The exact process will depend on the specific assumptions you can make about the input.

Comment: Hi Mark and thanks for your answer.  It assumes though that `articleText` is structured and in sentence format.  More times than not, it's not.  We have a lot of records where we have pages upon of comma-separated names that are both separated as groups as well as by last name, first name.  It's a mess to be honest.  There is no decipherable rule that can be inferred for a logical stop point that can be applied to all records.  It's unfortunate for our situation.

Comment: @Stpete111: Actually, this answer points out that it is *you* who has to be able to make some kind of assumption about the input, if you want to be able to tokenize it sensibly. The regex example was merely illustrating a possible assumption. If there is no underlying structure to the input, then there is in fact no answer to your question, is there?